# ローカルサーバにあるwebアプリをリモートサーバの転送先のURLで表示させることができない。

Tags: python, html, django

**前提・実現したいこと**
コマンドプロンプトを使用してローカルにあるPythonのDjangoで作成したwebアプリファイルをリモートサーバに転送すると転送先のURLで下記のようなエラーがでてしまいます。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
Template error:
In template /URL/polls/index.html, error at line 1
   argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath
   1 :  {% if latest_question_list %} 
   2 :     <ul>
   3 :     {% for question in latest_question_list %}
   4 :         <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
   5 :     {% endfor %}
   6 :     </ul>
   7 : {% else %}
   8 :     <p>No polls are available.</p>
   9 : {% endif %}

Exception Type: TypeError at /polls/
Exception Value: argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath
```

**該当のソースコード**
settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY =

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**試したこと**
settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [""]→ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

同様にsettings.py DATABASES

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),　→　'NAME': os.path.join str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
```

に変更したところURLは表示できず、マイグレーション、runserverは以下のようにエラーでました。

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

また、settings.py DATABASESの変更前も同様のエラーが発生しました。

**追記**

settings.py DATABASES

```
'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')),
```

に変更後、改めてローカルでマイグレーション、runserverし直したがエラー

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

同様にsettings.py DATABASES

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3')),
```

に変更後、ローカルでマイグレーション、runserve共にエラーなし。
しかし、リモート上では表示できず。

また、参考サイトではDjangoのバージョンが3以上となっていたが、リモート上のエラーではstr推奨のために

```
'NAME': os.path.join(str(BASE_DIR) , 'db.sqlite3')),
```

に変更してみたが、ローカルでマイグレーション、runserve共にエラーなし。
しかし、リモート上では表示できず。

**補足(ツールのバージョン等)**
python 3.6.9
django 2.2.7
windows10

Python,djangoのローカルとリモートのバージョンを統一済み。

**参考サイト**
https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/comments/17266

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/gn8ltkfkt61z5j

Answer (score 0):

最初のエラーに

```
argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath
```

とあるように`str`であるべき引数が`PosixPath`になっているのが原因かと思われます。

NAMEを以下のようにstrに変換してから渡すといかがでしょうか？

```
'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')),
```

こちらのリンクも参考になると思います。
https://utubou-tech.com/type-error_posixpath/

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。 'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')), に変更後、改めてローカルでマイグレーション、runserverし直しました、 unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'　とエラー。 また、 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3')), に変更後、ローカルでマイグレーション、runserve共にエラーなし。 しかし、リモート上では表示できない状態です。'NAME': os.path.join(str(BASE_DIR) , 'db.sqlite3')).も同様にローカルエラーなし、リモート上では表示できませんでした。